# Citing 'several' studies in one statement... cite all of them or use 'for example'?

Tags: citations

Let's assume that 10 empirical studies have been done for topic x. If I want to mention the following: Several studies have been conducted to deal with topic x (study 1; study 2; study 3).

My question: when I mention the word 'several', am I obligated to cite ALL the 10 empirical studies in the citation? Can I just cite a few? Should I use 'for example' to tell the reader that I am citing only 3 related studies, however others studies do exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the empirical studies with topic *X* involves the application of various methods associated with *X*, aspect of citing the number of available examples depends on your motive.

- If you are **illustrating** a method, then citing only a few like two or three would be fine. This can be when you wish to show the applicability (or inapplicability) of a method *Y* for the topic *X* citing only few of the papers that uses *Y* on *X*.
- On the other hand, if you wish to do a detailed study on different methods applied in different ways on topic *X*, then you would have to cite all the available empirical studies done on *X*. Note that you would also have to give an account on each of the material you have cited. This would be the obvious case for a proper **survey**.

Comment: Thanks for the illustrating example. I am just writing an essay and would like to inform my instructor that there exists many empirical studies done on topic X by showing her a few like (study 1; study 2; study 3), of course, there could be 10000 studies related to this topic, I don't want to cite ALL OF THEM! Can I just do like (study 1; study 2; study 3) without saying for example? I don't want my readers to assume that only 3 studies exist on this topic.

Comment: @R.AS.:  Just make sure you include the *'for example'* part along with the citation list. For instance, *"Many empirical studies have been done on X (e.g., [5], [7], [8])..."*. It would be better to explain at least one of them if you are stating this in the *Related Works / Literature Review* section.

Comment: Definitely. But is 'e.g.' the same as 'for example'? I am not sure...

Comment: @R.AS.: Yes absolutely. *E.g.* stands for *exempli gratia* used in the place of *'for example'*.

Answer (score 0):

If you doubt that a study should be included in the bibliography, then probably you don't consider it worth citing. Make a selection and then include every one of them in the bibliography. In the body you could say something like, "An exhaustive body of empirical studies exists on this topic [see: Study 1, Study 2,... Study N]. In particular, [Study X, Study Y] are most relevant to our work...".

Not including cited work in bibliography will be considered at best a sign of laziness and at worst an indication of unethical behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am not asking about bibliography. Of course, every study I am going to cite in-text is going to appear on my bibliography list. However, assume there are 100 studies related to X and all of them are related, should I write in-text: see study 1, study 2, study 3, study 4, ..., study 100 (e.g. ALL OF THEM) or can I only mention a few without saying 'for example' like see study 1, study 2, study 3.

Comment: That's why I suggested to make a selection of the most relevant ones. It's unlikely that there are dozens of case studies with unique/equally important findings. After a specific number of studies, the marginal utility of including additional studies quickly diminishes. Unless it's your job to really list of all possible studies ever published, stick to a few that best help your article.

Comment: Indeed. That's what I am looking for. Should I include something like 'for example' or 'e.g.' to inform my readers that my list (of 3 or 4) is not exhaustive and others studies do exist?